# Error message after update

Tags: updates, impresspages

With every update of ImpressPages 4 I receive the following error message:

Update has failed: rmdir(/pathtomyinstallation/tmp/update/extracted//Ip/lnternal/Vendor/Zend/I18n/Validator/PhoneNumber) [http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php'>function.rmdirphp]: Directory not empty in /pathtomyinstallation/Ip/Internal/Update/Helper/FiIeSystem.php:129{‘status':'success'}

Despite this error message the update works.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the script couldn't delete some file or folder. On Windows machines these is random but common issue. You just restart the update and second time that folder is deleted.